# Spring + Hibernate MVC - How to make browser can convert string to object automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing an java web project using Spring and Hibernate framework. As many of you knew, in Spring, within form:form, we can submit an object through @ModelAttribute (If I understand it wrong, please explain it for me).

```
<form:form action="student.do" method="GET" commandName="student">
  <form:input path="id"/>
  <form:input path="name"/>
  <form:input path="age"/>
</form:form>
```

With this form, the URL will be ?id=1&name=karliekloss&age=24. It is very simple, right?
But if I set up another object as a child of this Student Object example like HomeWork with elements: score, name. So if I do the same code above

```
<form:form action="student.do" method="GET" commandName="student">
  <form:input path="id"/>
  <form:input path="name"/>
  <form:input path="age"/>
  <form:select path="homeWork">
     <form:option itemValue="${value1}"/>
     <form:option itemValue="${value2}"/>
  </form:select>
</form:form>
```

The URL will display like this ?id=1&name=karliekloss&age=24&homeWork=model.HomeWork@4f0f43fe, I find out that the value 'model.HomeWork@4f0f43fe' is the result of toString() function of class HomeWork, my question is, how to override the toString() or what is the structure of String returned by toString() to make the controller can determine the Student object (with HomeWork object as a child), because it always returns "request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" .
Thank you for reading my issue and please help me!

**UPDATE** Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, @RequestParam String action,
        BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map) {
    switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
        case "add":
            break;
        case "update":
            break;
        case "cancel":
            break;
    }
    return "quantity";
}
```

Comment: @TimeTravel I updated it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `path="homework.score"` and `path="homework.name"` to set the values to the `HomeWork` object in the `Student` object, given that your your field names match with the ones specified in the `path` attribute. In this way your query parameters will be `&homework.score=90&homework.name=math`. No need to override the `toString()` method.

```
            <tr>
                <td>Homework Score:</td>
                <td><form:select path="homework.score"
                        items="${scoreList}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Homework Name:</td>
                <td><form:select path="homework.name"
                        items="${nameList}" /></td>
            </tr>
```

You can simply test this by printing these values in the controller - `student.getHomeWork().getScore();` and `student.getHomeWork().getName()`

Comment: Thanks, but it is inconvenience, because if i have a list of HomeWork object, I can't do that. Example, I have another type of object list like Color, which have 100 items and each Color item have id, name, code... so I have to make 3 or more list with 100 items?